# iOS 6 Core Data Relation Object insertObject issue

Tags: ios, core-data

In the below example code I am passing a`managedContext` object via a property of the view controller this selector lives in. In this case this property is `currentPetCoreDataObject`.

**Does someone have a simple project, not necessarily iOS project, that has a one to many relationship in it using the Core Data framework?  A simple command-line app would do.  All the examples with relationships that I can find are one to one.**

I don't know how to use the generated selector in the xCode Generated entity class and couldn't find any examples:

```
- (void)insertObject:(Feeding *)value inPetFeedRelationAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

The following code appears to work but when checking the count, it doesn't appear to be saving. What am I missing?

I am new to Core Data and have not yet successfully used a relation.

```
if (!self.nsMutableOrderedSetFeed)
{
  NSLog(@"current feed count:%d", self.currentPetCoreDataObject.PetFeedRelation.count);

    [self.addedFeedObject setBrand:self.txtBrand.text];
    [self.addedFeedObject setFood:self.txtType.text];
    [self.addedFeedObject setParentPetRelation:self.currentPetCoreDataObject];

    [self.addedFeedObject addPetFeedRelationObject:self.addedFeedObject];
    //[self.currentPetCoreDataObject insertObject:self.addedFeedObject inPetFeedRelationAtIndex:[self.currentPetCoreDataObject.PetFeedRelation i];

    [self.currentPetCoreDataObject setPetFeedRelation:[self.nsMutableOrderedSetFeed initWithObject:self.addedFeedObject]];
}
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    NSLog(@"Failed to add new Pet profile with error: %@", [error domain]);

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing  `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]` with `[self.currentPetCoreDataObject save:&error]` and seen if that works.  Maybe `self.managedObjectContext` is nil

Comment: Turns out that I had setup my Data Model incorrectly. 1. I had the relations setup as child entities(doesn't do what you would guess) 2. I needed to set the "plural To-Many Relationship" option for the entity containing the relation. 3. I had to create a new nsOrderedSet, add the set data items and then set the relation to reference the new nsOrderedSet.